# Is it possible to write a javascript SSH client that uses web sockets for transport?

Tags: javascript, ssh, websocket, orbited

Would it be possible to write a basic SSH client in pure javascript using something like orbited web sockets as the transport layer?  I don't see any examples of this, but it seems like it would be a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) and [rTerm](http://xant.us/ext-ux/examples/rterm/), which uses it.
I really like Orbited and used it on one of my company's internal systems (with RabbitMQ). It should be possible to take the concepts from those applications and use Orbited as the transport layer, though I don't think this is the best use case for it (as the task being single-user and not channel-based etc.).

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I think I'm going to use anyterm.  Appreciate the help.

http://anyterm.org/1.1/install.html

Answer (score 2):

With a proxy on the server to convert the unpack the WebSocket protocol and tunnel it into SSH, sure, it could be done.

It hasn't been done yet because WebSocket isn't really finished yet and most browsers don't have implementations. You have to fall back to Flash sockets to emulate it.